# How to add elements to a Bitmap list from the file system? - C#

Tags: c#, file, bitmap, static

In frmPrincipal I have this:

```
List<int> ListaIndicesImagenes;

public frmPrincipal()
        {
            ...

            ListaIndicesImagenes = new List<int>(AccesoImagenes.ObtenerCantidadImagenes());
        }
```

That line throws the following exception:

```
System.TypeInitializationException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233036
  Message=Se produjo una excepción en el inicializador de tipo de 'Juego.AccesoImagenes'.
  Source=Juego
  TypeName=Juego.AccesoImagenes
  StackTrace:
       en Juego.AccesoImagenes.ObtenerCantidadImagenes()
       en Juego.frmPrincipal..ctor() en c:\Users\Sebastián\OneDrive\Visual Studio Projects\Juego\Juego\frmPrincipal.cs:línea 57
       en Juego.Program.Main() en c:\Users\Sebastián\OneDrive\Visual Studio Projects\Juego\Juego\Program.cs:línea 19
       en System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       en System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       en Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       en System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       en System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       en System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       en System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       en System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException: System.NotSupportedException
       HResult=-2146233067
       Message=No se admite el formato proporcionado de la ruta de acceso.
       Source=mscorlib
       StackTrace:
            en System.Security.Util.StringExpressionSet.CanonicalizePath(String path, Boolean needFullPath)
            en System.Security.Util.StringExpressionSet.CreateListFromExpressions(String[] str, Boolean needFullPath)
            en System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.AddPathList(FileIOPermissionAccess access, AccessControlActions control, String[] pathListOrig, Boolean checkForDuplicates, Boolean needFullPath, Boolean copyPathList)
            en System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission..ctor(FileIOPermissionAccess access, String[] pathList, Boolean checkForDuplicates, Boolean needFullPath)
            en System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(String path)
            en System.Drawing.IntSecurity.UnsafeGetFullPath(String fileName)
            en System.Drawing.IntSecurity.DemandReadFileIO(String fileName)
            en System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor(String filename)
            en Juego.AccesoImagenes..cctor() en c:\Users\Sebastián\OneDrive\Visual Studio Projects\Juego\Juego\AccesoImagenes.cs:línea 31
       InnerException:
```

AccesoImagenes class goes like this:

```
public class AccesoImagenes
{
    private static string[] arregloDif;// = Directory.GetFiles(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"Diferentes\");
    private static string[] arregloIguales;// = Directory.GetFiles(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"Iguales\");
    private static string[] arregloOriginales;// = Directory.GetFiles(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"Originales\");
    private static List<Bitmap> listaDif;// = new List<Bitmap>();
    private static List<Bitmap> listaIgual;// = new List<Bitmap>();
    private static List<Bitmap> listaOriginales;// = new List<Bitmap>();

    static AccesoImagenes()
    {
        arregloDif = Directory.GetFiles(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"Diferentes\\");
        arregloIguales = Directory.GetFiles(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"Iguales\\");
        arregloOriginales = Directory.GetFiles(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"Originales\\");
        listaDif = new List<Bitmap>();
        listaIgual = new List<Bitmap>();
        listaOriginales = new List<Bitmap>();
//here comes the damn exception

        for (int i = 0; i < arregloDif.Length; i++)
        {
            listaDif.Add(new Bitmap(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"Diferentes\\" + arregloDif[i]));
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < arregloIguales.Length; i++)
        {
            listaIgual.Add(new Bitmap(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"Iguales\\" + arregloIguales[i]));
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < arregloOriginales.Length; i++)
        {
            listaOriginales.Add(new Bitmap(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"Originales\\" + arregloOriginales[i]));
        }
    }
    public AccesoImagenes()
    {

    }
    public static Bitmap[] ObtenerParImagenes(int Indice, bool Iguales)
    {
        Bitmap[] Imagenes = new Bitmap[2];
        Imagenes[0] = listaOriginales[Indice];
        if (Iguales == true)
        {
            Imagenes[1] = listaIgual[Indice];
        }
        else
        {
            Imagenes[1] = listaDif[Indice];
        }
        return Imagenes;
    }
    public static int ObtenerCantidadImagenes()
    {
        return arregloOriginales.Length;
    }
```

The exception fires up as soon as the static constructor reaches the first 'for' loop to fill the first bitmap list.

Sorry if portions of the exception text and names into the code are in Spanish, should I translate something?

Does someone understand what the heck is going on??

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I just solved this, I found that the string arrays already contained the full absolute route for the files I needed, so when adding them to the lists, instead of this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arregloDif.Length; i++)
        {
            listaDif.Add(new Bitmap(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"Diferentes\\" + arregloDif[i]));
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < arregloIguales.Length; i++)
        {
            listaIgual.Add(new Bitmap(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"Iguales\\" + arregloIguales[i]));
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < arregloOriginales.Length; i++)
        {
            listaOriginales.Add(new Bitmap(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"Originales\\" + arregloOriginales[i]));
        }
```

I now have this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arregloDif.Length; i++)
            {
                listaDif.Add(new Bitmap(/*AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"Diferentes\\" + */arregloDif[i]));
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < arregloIguales.Length; i++)
            {
                listaIgual.Add(new Bitmap(/*AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"Iguales\\" + */arregloIguales[i]));
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < arregloOriginales.Length; i++)
            {
                listaOriginales.Add(new Bitmap(/*AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"Originales\\" + */arregloOriginales[i]));
            }
```

Now another weird exception is being thrown, but that's for other question

Answer (score 0):

One of these lines is likely throwing the exception:

```
arregloDif = Directory.GetFiles(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"Diferentes\\");
        arregloIguales = Directory.GetFiles(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"Iguales\\");
        arregloOriginales = Directory.GetFiles(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"Originales\\");
```

It is likely that the directories that one of the directories you are trying to access does not exist or is inaccessible for some other reason.

It is hard to tell because you didn't post all of the inner exceptions, but the 1st inner exception is a System.NotSupportedException.  The other inner exception that is not listed likely has more important info in it.

You also appear to be using the @ symbol incorrectly, but I don't think it is causing your problem.

You have both `@` and `\\`.
You should probably be using one or the other.

Here is an example of correct usage:

```
string path = @"C:\Test";
string path = "C:\\Test";
```

Comment: Thank you for the input, I'll correct the @ usage, but those three lines execute without problems and I get 3 arrays containing the names of all the files stored in the 3 folders. The exception is thrown when the constructor reaches the first for, so I guess it has to do with the new Bitmap method, but it shouldn't... I pasted all the exception info as it was (I clicked the link "Copy exception detail to clipborad") but I'll double check

Comment: What is the innermost exception?  That should help you identify the problem.

Comment: I can confirm, there is no inner exception.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense!  The exception output you posted ends with "InnerException:", and there is nothing after that!

Comment: Would it help if I posted a skydrive link to the project?